# Deploying ignored dist folder to GitHub Pages

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I have created a Git repo for a JavaScript library. The repo also contains a demo website that uses the bundled library, which is generated in a `dist/` folder. I would now like to deploy that website to GitHub Pages.

However, I have the `dist/` folder in my `.gitignore` and would prefer it to remain ignored.

Is there a way to automatically generate the `gh-pages` branch, which should include `dist/`, but keep it off the `master` branch?

Comment: Hint 1: `.gitignore` in different branches can be different; `.gitignore` in code and doc branches certainly should be different. Hint 2: you can add and commit even ignored files: `git add --force`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Commit this script and call it after having built your `dist`:

```
#!/bin/sh

git commit -am "Save uncommited changes (WIP)"
git branch --delete --force gh-pages
git checkout --orphan gh-pages
git add -f dist
git commit -m "Rebuild GitHub pages"
git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter dist && git push -f origin gh-pages && git checkout -
```

I use it for that ;-)

Comment: Maybe you could add `git reset` after doing `git checkout --orphan gh-pages` ? otherwise all the tracked files on master (not only dist) will be committed in branch gh-pages (of course, in the end the `git filter-branch ...` command will purge the content outside of dist folder, but I believe it is more idiomatic to do `git reset` after the orphan checkout)

Comment: BTW a drawback of this solution is that we lose the history of branch gh-pages at each invocation of the script. (If this is an issue for the OP, this drawback doesn't occur with the [bash solution](https://github.com/X1011/git-directory-deploy) I had mentioned in my answer.)

Comment: On second thought it's better not to do `git reset` after `git checkout --orphan gh-pages` in this case, because if there is a file e.g. `README.md` in both `dist` and root folder of the repo, the `git filter-branch ...` command would raise `error: Untracked working tree file 'README.md' would be overwritten by merge.`

Comment: @ErikMD Indeed, the gh-page history is lost but it's not a problem for me (made it on design to not have 2 long history in parallel when looking at branch history). But removing `git branch` and `--orphan` should solve that if you want to keep the history.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize your context:

- your current branch is `master`
- you have a `dist/` folder that is ignored and untracked
- it contains the sources of a website that can be statically served
- you'd like to publish this `dist/` folder on GitHub Pages using a `gh-pages` branch.

The simplest way to do this seems to follow the workflow suggested in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490)
as well as in the [documentation of Yeoman](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman.github.io/blob/source/app/learning/deployment.md#git-subtree-command).

But note that this relies on the advanced command [git subtree](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree) and requires that the `dist/` folder is not ignored and tracked on `master` as well.

You could then follow the doc regarding the [configuration of GH Pages' publishing source](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/).

Does this address your question or do you really want to have the two branches separated and no `dist/*` file in the `master` branch?

In the latter case, the problem is more complicated (because of the untracked or ignored files in the work tree that can hinder the process...) but you may want to have a look at [this project](https://github.com/X1011/git-directory-deploy), which is an alternative to the `git subtree`-based solution, and is based on a Bash script.

(Note: I have not tested this "git-directory-deploy" solution; it was suggested in the [gist](https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490#gistcomment-1243110) I mentioned above.)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, Travis CI or another continuous integration tool could be used to automatically create the build and deploy the generated files on the `gh-pages` branch: [GitHub Pages Deployment](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/pages/)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20200222120227/http://covidence.engineering/deploy-directory-to-branch/), I finally found a convenient way to **forge a commit from a gitignored subfolder on top of another branch**. I personally use it to release a built npm package in a release dedicated branch.

Using such a solution is very flexible, keeps history (no need to force push), but involves more git internals:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Environment
BUILD_DIR="dist"
RELEASE_BRANCH="gh-pages"
VERSION="$(jq -r ".version" package.json)"

# Script
git fetch origin $RELEASE_BRANCH
git add -f $BUILD_DIR
tree=$(git write-tree --prefix=$BUILD_DIR)
git reset -- $BUILD_DIR
identifier=$(git describe --dirty --always)
commit=$(git commit-tree -p refs/remotes/origin/$RELEASE_BRANCH -m "Deploy $identifier as v$VERSION" $tree)
git update-ref refs/heads/$RELEASE_BRANCH $commit
git tag -a "v$VERSION" -m "Release tag for $VERSION" $commit
git push --follow-tags origin refs/heads/$RELEASE_BRANCH
```