# GIT remove history for removed files in folder

Tags: git, github, github-actions, github-pages

I have a GIT repo in which I have two folders which are managed with some GH actions and forwarded to GH pages. The first folder (name it `data/`) contains compressed historical data collected periodically through GH actions. The second folder (name it `docs/`) contains the uncompressed data for the latest collection and some additional HTML files which are meant for the GH pages. This second folder is also updated on the same periodicity as the first folder - and in this sense, the contents is fully removed (`git rm *` and `git push`) before updating it (`tar x` followed by `git add/commit/push`)

Since the uncompressed data is quite large, the GIT repo keeps growing and growing. However, I'm not interested in keeping a history of this second folder - I only want to keep the latest update, so is there any way to remove the history of this second folder to save space?

Comment: Why not `git filter-repo` on that folder and force push?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158271/7976758 `git rebase`, `git filter-branch`, whatever https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+files+history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly an answer to your question but for me you should change your workflow of publishing the github page as you try to do something that goes against how git is working...

You should put the result of the github page in another branch (for example `gh-pages`) and publish the github pages from this branch.

And for this `gh-pages` branch, do not keep history (done with the command `git checkout --orphan gh-pages` in the following script).

You could do it with a script I provided [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48591941/717372).

Adapt the script to publish the `docs` **untracked** folder (instead of the `dist` one), where you will have built your documentation without committing it.

**That way, you won't have to rewrite the history because your big folder will never be committed in the main branch.**

Settings to change in GitHub project to select the other branch:

[image: github pages setting]